# Echo isn't working within a section of my PHP

Tags: php, html, text, echo

Okay, so I am trying to display text when something goes wrong. I want to have it so that if the page number is too high (above 3 in my case) it will display an error. Disregard the accessing mySQL database.

```
<?php
    function get($name)
    {
        return isset($_REQUEST[$name]) ? $_REQUEST[$name] : '';
    }

    function is_valid_index($index,$array)
    {
        return $index >= 0 && $index < count($array);

    }
?>




<?php

    //Variables

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "pass";
$dberror = "You have failed to connect to the database!";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ($dberror);

$select_db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "database") or die ("Couldn't Select Database");
?>

<form>
<?php
        $page = array('Select List','Users', 'Groups');

        echo '<select name="Lists">';
            for($i = 0;
            $i < count($page);
            $i++)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.($i + 1).'">'.$page[$i].'</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
?>
    <input type='submit'>
    </form>
<?php
    if(get('page'))
    {
            $page_id = get('page');
            if(is_valid_index($page_id-1,$page))
            {
                echo "You have selected".$page[$page_id-1];
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<span style="color:red">Invalid Page</span>';
            }
    }
?>
```

Got the tutorial from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaRh2HauIXY

Comment: Can you please be clearer about what is not working? Are you getting any error out of it?

Comment: If you scroll towards the bottom (I'm not sure how to highlight yet) you will see the part right after the form. I open PHP and try to get the ID of whatever I have selected from the form.

Comment: I've got what you are doing, the problem is: **what is the problem exactly?** in your question you say: _Echo isn't working within a section of my PHP_ and it's fine, but what section? and what is happening instead?

Comment: Oh, okay. The echo(s) that are not working are the
echo "You have selected".$page[$page_id-1];
and the
echo '<span style="color:red">Invalid Page</span>';
I'm not sure if it is even reading what I select.

Comment: If the part inside `if(get('page')){..}` isn't echoing, then obviously `get('page')` is returning `false`. Try echoing the result of `get('page')` first

Comment: And is it printing '<span style="color:red">Invalid Page</span>' instead? or isn't that printing anything at all? if so, the error is that the **get()** function is returning false or ''. This is probably related to the fact that you are not submitting anything with **name="page"**. Try changing: `echo '<select name="Lists">';` to: `echo '<select name="page">'`, because you are actually sending Lists instead of page. The alternative is changing `get('page')` to `get('Lists')`, your choice now ;).

Comment: How is the `$_REQUEST` data being set? Is it from the form in the code you have provided? Because if so, you're not passing a `$_REQUEST['page']` value.

Comment: Thank you so much briosheje! I completely forgot that I had changed it to "page" instead of "Lists" and forgot to triple check. It works great now and I truly thank you! I've also improved my code a bit.

Comment: Please make an answer briosheje so you can get the credit for this one :)

Comment: @cj89898 : It's fine, accept Alex Andrei's answer, I'm not sure if he read that from the comments or what ( I **Don't** think so, though ) , but I'm just instered about the fact that your code is actually working, that's the important thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
echo '<select name="Lists">';
```

into this

```
echo '<select name="page">';
```

this way the function `get('page')` will return `true` and the `if` block will execute and so will your `echo` calls

Comment: i just saw that it was already answered by @briosheje in the comments section.

Comment: It's fine, I believe you didn't read that from the comments, so it's okay ;). Please accept this answer

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence, I spent some time formatting the text. Then I tried to delete the answer when I saw the top comments but it doesn't work that way, then added my comment in ... I'm new to actually contributing to SO :)

Comment: Welp, thank you both for the efforts to help me out :) Code is working flawlessly now!